# Can Firebase keep two different database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a project on barcode scanner mobile apps. Can I do a login/registration database in Firebase and also a database for information from the barcode (that store the ID, itemName and price) ?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want the two types of data to be in two separate databases? Can't they just be separate nodes in the same database?

Comment: I am doing separate database because I thought that the login/registration database is for "user" database, and information from the barcode would be "item" database. Is that can be possible to be in separate nodes but in same database?

Comment: Yes. In a relational database those would just be two tables. In Firebase Realtime Database, they'd be two top-level nodes with child nodes under them. That'll be a lot easier to manage than creating a separate database instance for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the "database sharding" features provided by firebase. More details 
here : [Connect your app to multiple database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding)

Then you can connect your Android app to multiple database instances like mentioned in the demo :

```
// Get the default database instance for an app
DatabaseReference primary = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference();

// Get a secondary database instance by URL
DatabaseReference secondary = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com")
        .getReference();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. you will just have to create two collection in your Database one for login/registration and another for data from the barcode.[refer this image i have use two collections (User for login/registration) & sentences for other data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLGNQ.png)

Comment: In addition - you can use both firestore and Realtime database in the same project